# katharsis-rs URL decoding

Tags: katharsis

I am using Katharsis libraries katharsis-core and katharsis-rs for JAX-RS Integration of Katharsis. Version I am using is 2.4.0. Is there any updates on these libraries, where Katharsis automatically performs URL Decoding before parsing the filter parameter? I see that katharsis-servlet has updates on this, but could not find one for katharsis-core. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.6 is available and there has been a lot of work done on query param parsing. Just update your pom.